# How to find next bigger / equal text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this

```
 id   |     name   
------+-----------
 1    |     aaa
 5    |     aaa
 2    |     bbb
 4    |     bbb
 10   |     bbb
 7    |     ccc
 9    |     ccc
```

In my Windows Forms app, I need to "find next" button

- first find "aaa" with id 1
- then  find "aaa" with id 5
- and then find "bbb" with id 2

I use this query

```
select  
    min(name)  
from 
    table 
where 
    [name] >='@name'
```

but it always returns "aaa"

and

```
select  
    min(name)  
from 
    table 
where 
   [name] >'@name'
```

this does not return other id's

Comment: Please add a tag for database+version

Comment: it should be `select  min(id)  from table where [name] >'@name'` but it would not return the next id

Comment: You can *sort* the records and then on each button click read 1st, 2nd, 3d etc. records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      top 1
            [name],[id]

from        [table] 

where       (   [name]  = @name 
            and [id]    > @id
            )
        or  [name] > @name 

order by    [name],[id]
```

or

`lead` looks on the next row when the rows are ordered by the `order by` expressions within the `over` clause.

```
select      [name],[next_id] as [id]

from       (select  [id],[name],lead([id]) over (order by [name],@id) as [next_id]
            from    [table] 
            ) t

where       [name]  = @name 
        and [id]    = @id
```

Comment: at least a little bit of explanation would be wise.

Comment: yea, mine doesn't work :P i am just not sure if the condition of the first one can do the trick to solve the name changing scenario. and i am not good enough to read the second one .... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can *sort* the records and then on each button click just read the next record:

```
  select name,
         id 
    from Table
order by name,
         id
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think this is what you want:

```
create table TestTable(id int, name nvarchar(max))
GO

insert into TestTable
values
(1, 'aaa'),
(5, 'aaa'),
(2, 'bbb'),
(4, 'bbb'),
(10, 'bbb'),
(7, 'ccc'),
(9, 'ccc')
GO

create function dbo.FindNext(@lastResultOrdinal int) returns nvarchar(max)
as begin
    return (select name from TestTable order by name, id offset @lastResultOrdinal rows fetch next 1 rows only)
end
GO

create function dbo.LastOrdinalWasLast(@lastResultOrdinal int) returns bit
as begin
    if ((select count(id) from TestTable) = @lastResultOrdinal)
        return 1
    return 0
end
GO

--Fetching First Result:
select dbo.FindNext(0)
select dbo.LastOrdinalWasLast(1)

--Fetching Last Result:
select dbo.FindNext(6)
select dbo.LastOrdinalWasLast(7)
```

The `dbo.FindNext` function supposed to do the work giving it the ordinal (zero-based index + 1) of the current row; while `dbo.LastOrdinalWasLast` makes sure that there's no more rows to fetch.